# sed - how can I cover optional space?

Tags: unix, sed

Probably this is a dumb question but here we go! I am using sed to remove a content from file and sometimes it doesnt have a space character:

myfile

```
resource "love" {
   ...
}
```

myfile2

```
resource "love"{
   ...
}
```

My command:

```
sed -i '' -e '/resource "love" {/,/}/d;/resource "love"{/,/}/d'
```

Do you have another option to consider that space as optional character and cover both situations instead of copy/paste sed instruction?

Answer (score 2):

With perl:

```
perl -i -0pe 's/ressouce "love"\s*.*?\}//s' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Match zero or more using `sed`

```
$ sed -i "" '/resource "love" *{/,/}/d' input_file
```